# why is my UncaughtExceptionHandler not catching StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, stack-overflow, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I am running a Java daemon and want to catch unhandled exceptions. So I wrote a class:

```
public class CodeineUncaughtExceptionHandler 
    implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

  private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CodeineUncaughtExceptionHandler.class);
  private boolean errorPrintedToOut = false;

  public CodeineUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
  }

  @Override
  public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
    try {
      if (!errorPrintedToOut) {
        errorPrintedToOut = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      log.error("Uncaught exception in thread " + t.getName(), e);
    } catch (Throwable tr) {
      try {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tr.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Throwable e1) {
        log.fatal("could not write stacktrace of exception " + t.getName());
        addExceptionInfo(e1);
        addExceptionInfo(e);
        addExceptionInfo(tr);
      }
    }
  }

  private void addExceptionInfo(Throwable e) {
    log.fatal("exception info " + e.getMessage() + " " + e);
  }
}
```

and it is used like this:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CodeineUncaughtExceptionHandler());
```

For some reason it seems not to work. From the documentation it looks this should be applied to all threads. However my output file is missing the full stacktrace of the exception:

> Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "qtp18824904-18"

Any Idea?

Comment: Then the problem is not that it is not caught, is it? You should edit the title of the question

Comment: I don't know if it caught or not.

Comment: Without any doubt, your exception handler **has worked** but has thrown a `StackOverflowError`, for some reason. Can you provide some self-contained example code that reproduces this issue? In principle your code works fine on my machine.

Comment: How can you tell whether or not your UEH is working?  Add something to your UEH to let you know it is has done something.  `print("In UEH.");` or whatever.

Comment: I dont have any - log.error entries so I assume uncaughtExceptionHandler is not called, but I am not sure.

Comment: @oshai Maybe the logging is related to your `StackOverflowError`. Try just printing to stdout to rule out logging issues. Basically, simplify your handler and increase its complexity until you spot what triggers the exception.

Comment: it might happen that your jetty's worker thread are started way before and blew up and then you added your handler.

Comment: @Duncan - I cant provide such code, I don't have an idea how to reproduce it.

Comment: @oshai So you've only seen this happen once? Or does it happen sporadically? You should change your title to "*Why is my UncaughtExceptionHandler throwing a StackOverflowError?*".

Comment: @Duncan - yes, it happens sporadically. I am willing to change the title If you are sure this is the cause. I thought maybe `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` was called again after my code. is it possible?

Comment: @oshai Well, anything's possible. But a StackOverflowError has certainly been thrown from an uncaught exception handler. I think it's highly likely your own registered handler has thrown it. If in doubt, add `System.out.println("HARRRRR!");` as the first line in your handler.

Comment: Thanks, I added a print in the beginning of the handler.